# What property type converters come built-in with Spring?

Tags: java, spring

What are the supported values for the `targetType` parameter in the Spring framework method [PropertyResolver.getProperty(String key, Class targetType)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-)? I'm looking for a list of types that are supported by default.

The following types work apparently:

- Locale.class
- int.class
- File.class
- URI.class

Example:

```
// works
Locale myLocale = propertyResolver.getProperty("my.locale", Locale.class);
```

I found this list:
http://www.logicbig.com/how-to/spring-framework/spring-converters-list/
But it doesn't list `File` or `URI`, so it doesn't seem to be complete. Also, I would prefer official documentation.

I didn't find anything in the [reference documentation chapter on type conversion](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) either.

Comment: The [DefaultConversionService](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/b22a59a0c4ea118147dc45c563d68234b8692d97/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/DefaultConversionService.java) defines a bunch of built-in converters. That's probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the following to figure it out:

Define a single bean in my context.xml

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean"/>
```

Then I do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:context.xml")) {
            ConversionService service = context.getBean(ConversionService.class);
            System.out.println(service);
        }
}
```

And I get

```
ConversionService converters =
    java.lang.Boolean -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToStringConverter@520a3426
    java.lang.Character -> java.lang.Number : org.springframework.core.convert.support.CharacterToNumberFactory@6b09bb57
    java.lang.Character -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToStringConverter@5f9d02cb
    java.lang.Enum -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.core.convert.support.EnumToStringConverter@3e9b1010
    java.lang.Number -> java.lang.Character : org.springframework.core.convert.support.NumberToCharacterConverter@63753b6d
    java.lang.Number -> java.lang.Number : org.springframework.core.convert.support.NumberToNumberConverterFactory@527740a2
    java.lang.Number -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToStringConverter@3108bc
    java.lang.String -> java.lang.Boolean : org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToBooleanConverter@6536e911
    java.lang.String -> java.lang.Character : org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToCharacterConverter@370736d9
    java.lang.String -> java.lang.Enum : org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToEnumConverterFactory@18eed359
    java.lang.String -> java.lang.Number : org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToNumberConverterFactory@13a5fe33
    java.lang.String -> java.nio.charset.Charset : org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToCharsetConverter@185d8b6
    java.lang.String -> java.util.Currency : org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToCurrencyConverter@335eadca
    java.lang.String -> java.util.Locale : org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToLocaleConverter@6c3708b3
    java.lang.String -> java.util.Properties : org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToPropertiesConverter@eec5a4a
    java.lang.String -> java.util.TimeZone : org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToTimeZoneConverter@61f8bee4
    java.lang.String -> java.util.UUID : org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToUUIDConverter@6ddf90b0
    java.nio.charset.Charset -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToStringConverter@67784306
    java.time.ZoneId -> java.util.TimeZone : org.springframework.core.convert.support.ZoneIdToTimeZoneConverter@7b49cea0
    java.time.ZonedDateTime -> java.util.Calendar : org.springframework.core.convert.support.ZonedDateTimeToCalendarConverter@887af79
    java.util.Currency -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToStringConverter@210366b4
    java.util.Locale -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToStringConverter@6f1fba17
    java.util.Properties -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.core.convert.support.PropertiesToStringConverter@2b2948e2
    java.util.UUID -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToStringConverter@57536d79
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ArrayToArrayConverter@4b4523f8
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ArrayToCollectionConverter@3b0143d3
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ArrayToObjectConverter@7791a895
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ArrayToStringConverter@1f28c152
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ByteBufferConverter@4f970963
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ByteBufferConverter@4f970963
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ByteBufferConverter@4f970963
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ByteBufferConverter@4f970963
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.CollectionToArrayConverter@5a8e6209
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.CollectionToCollectionConverter@731a74c
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.CollectionToObjectConverter@67b92f0a
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.CollectionToStringConverter@6325a3ee
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.FallbackObjectToStringConverter@6e0e048a
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.IdToEntityConverter@7fac631b,org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToObjectConverter@5b87ed94
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.MapToMapConverter@369f73a2
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToArrayConverter@3a5ed7a6
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToCollectionConverter@2b9627bc
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToOptionalConverter@5bc79255
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.StreamConverter@65e2dbf3
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.StreamConverter@65e2dbf3
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.StreamConverter@65e2dbf3
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.StreamConverter@65e2dbf3
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToArrayConverter@7d907bac
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToCollectionConverter@1d16f93d
```

Those are the default converters offered in the [DefaultConversionService](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/b22a59a0c4ea118147dc45c563d68234b8692d97/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/DefaultConversionService.java) I mentioned in the comments section of your question.

I noticed there is a [FallbackObjectToStringConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/bc14c5ba83e1f211628456bbccce7b2531aac58c/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/FallbackObjectToStringConverter.java) which pretty much converts anything to a String. And so `URI` and `File` to `String` would always work. The reverse case seems to be handled by the [ObjectToObjectConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/9659bc5fe7ad70811bae0b2057194b47d5a506cd/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/ObjectToObjectConverter.java) which is smart enough to use constructors to get an object back from a String representation.

I suppose that depending on the libraries and Spring dependencies that you're using, chances are that they register more converters here.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [PropertyResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html) *Java* docs, you will see that it has a list of direct known sub interfaces. One such interface is the `ConfigurablePropertyResolver` interface. If you proceed to the [ConfigurablePropertyResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurablePropertyResolver.html) *Java* docs, you will see that they talk about the [ConversionService](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/ConversionService.html) interface. You will then find that [DefaultConversionService](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/support/DefaultConversionService.html) is one of the interfaces that implements `ConversionService` and has the following *Java* doc description :

> A specialization of GenericConversionService configured by default
>   with converters appropriate for most environments. Designed for direct
>   instantiation but also exposes the static
>   addDefaultConverters(ConverterRegistry) utility method for ad hoc use
>   against any ConverterRegistry instance.

It looks like this is the place where they have configured all the default converters. If you take a look at the [source-code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-core/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/core/convert/support/DefaultConversionService.java#DefaultConversionService.addDefaultConverters%28org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConverterRegistry%29) for `DefaultConversionService`, you will find that it calls the `addDefaultConverters` method in it's constructor. This method seems to setup all the convertors that are available by default.

**Note** The objective of this answer was to demonstrate how one can navigate through the available *Java* docs with a combination of source-code to get the info that they are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful, I'll keep it in mind for my next problem :-)